# Making a contingency table with continous variable

Tags: python

i'm stuck on a problem in python. i want to create a contingency table but i have variable which is continous. 
suppose:

```
a=[1,2,5,9,10,11.3,11.9,12.5,18.8]
b=["yes","no","yes","no","yes","no","no","no","yes"]
```

and i want to create a contingency table that looks like

```
              yes   | no
[1,8]          2      1
[9,18.8]       2      4
```

how to do that? thanks in advance. i look over several functions in pandas, like cut and crosstab, but i am not able to reach my purpose.

Comment: Could you explain how the values of the table are calculated?

Comment: simply looking at vector "a". first element of vector a is 1. so it's in the class[1,8]. it has label "yes"( see in vector b). so count it in  the intersection beetwen [1-8] and yes.

Answer (score 3):

A [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) solution would be like this:

Construct the dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"a": a, "b": b})
```

Use [pd.cut](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.cut.html) to find the intervals and pass that to [crosstab](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.crosstab.html):

```
pd.crosstab(pd.cut(df['a'], bins = [1, 8, 18.8], include_lowest=True), df['b'])
Out[41]: 
b          no  yes
a                 
[1, 8]      1    2
(8, 18.8]   4    2
```